# Analyse binary dataset row-wise regarding value after a one

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, if-statement

I want to calculate whether an individual survived from one year to the next or not. 0 means it died and 1 that it survived. The dataset consist of different years (2007 to 2020) and the calculation should start with year 2008. I only want R to use a proportion of the data I have.

My data set looks like the following:

[the first 17 rows of my data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE9w4.png)

```
> ID 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020
   1   0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0   0   0  
   3   0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0   0   0 
   4   0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0   0   0
   9   0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0   0   0
   24  0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1   1   0
  ...
```

In total I have 1,121 entries, 16 total columns.

I want R to start in the first row in year 2008 and see whether there is a 1 or not. If there is a 1, I want R to look at the next column (2009) and see if there is also a 1 (should give me a 1 as output) or a 0 (should give me a 0 as output).  If there is no 1 I want R to check the next columns until it find a year with a 1 then it should check the next column as described above. After it found a 1 and did the checking it should ignore the remaining columns and move to the next row and repeat the process. The output should be saved in a new column.

I tried for loop and if else statement as well as ifelse, if ...

The closest I was able to get to my goal is with the following code

```
for(x in foal_fates_2)) {
  if (foal_fates_2$`2008`=="1" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="1") {
    print("1")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "1" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0") {
    print("0")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="1" && foal_fates_2$`2010` == "1"){
    print("1")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="1" && foal_fates_2$`2010`== "0") {
    print("0")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="1" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="1"){
    print("1")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="1" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0"){
    print("0")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="1" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="1"){
    print("1")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="1" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="0"){
    print("0")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="1" && foal_fates_2$`2013`=="1"){
    print("1")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="1" && foal_fates_2$`2013`=="0"){
    print("0")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2013`=="1" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2014`== "1"){
    print("1")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2013`=="1" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2014`=="0"){
    print("0")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2013`=="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2014`== "1" && foal_fates_2$`2015`=="1"){
    print("1")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
            foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2013`=="0" &&
            foal_fates_2$`2014`== "1" && foal_fates_2$`2015`=="0"){
    print("0")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2013`=="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2014`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2015`=="1" && foal_fates_2$`2016` =="1"){
    print("1")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2013`=="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2014`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2015`=="1" && foal_fates_2$`2016` =="0"){
    print("0")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2013`=="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2014`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2015`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2016` =="1" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2017`=="1"){
    print("1")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2013`=="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2014`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2015`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2016` =="1" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2017`=="0"){
    print("0")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2013`=="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2014`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2015`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2016` =="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2017`=="1" && foal_fates_2$`2018`=="1"){
    print("1")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2013`=="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2014`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2015`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2016` =="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2017`=="1" && foal_fates_2$`2018`=="0"){
    print("0")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2013`=="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2014`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2015`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2016` =="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2017`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2018`=="1" && foal_fates_2$`2019`=="1"){
    print("1")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2013`=="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2014`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2015`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2016` =="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2017`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2018`=="1" && foal_fates_2$`2019`=="0"){
    print("0")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2013`=="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2014`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2015`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2016` =="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2017`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2018`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2019`=="1" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2020`=="1"){
    print("1")
  } else if (foal_fates_2$`2008`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2009` =="0" && foal_fates_2$`2010` =="0" && 
             foal_fates_2$`2011`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2012`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2013`=="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2014`== "0" && foal_fates_2$`2015`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2016` =="0" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2017`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2018`=="0" && foal_fates_2$`2019`=="1" &&
             foal_fates_2$`2020`=="0"){
    print("0")
  }
```

}

With this code R at least does something, and the result has the correct number of entities but the output is not correct. R gives me 0 and 1 but not at the correct place. Meaning e.g. for the first five rows R gave me the results "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" but it should be "0" "1" "1" "1" "0". At least if I understand it correctly. I am new to R so maybe for loop and if else are not the right tools for what I want to do. So, the question is how can I get to my goal. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: To understand the question correct, you are looking for all rows where two or more consecutive ones occur? Correct?

Comment: Yes for all rows but I only want the first "1" and then the following number after the first "1" of each row, the rest (consecutive or not) in the same row should be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a function to be applied on each row.
Something like the following one (which could of course be more elaborate, but should do the job):

```
numberAfterFirstOne <- function(myRow){
  x <- which(myRow == 1)[1] 
  if (length(x + 1) < length(myRow)) # 
    return(myRow[x + 1])
  else 
    return(NA)
}
```

Explanation:

1. Which indices are equal to one, just select the first one; if none is 1, x will be NA.
2. if there is a value after that first one, return it
3. return NA (could be also 0 or whatever 'key value' you wish

For testing here is an example dataset:

```
n <- 5
m <- 16
set.seed(1562) # for reproducability
dataset <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = m, nrow = n, data = round(runif(m * n, 0, 0.7))))
dataset <- rbind(dataset, rep(0, 16))

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16
1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0
2  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0
3  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
4  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0
5  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0
6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Then `apply` the function `numberAfterFirstOne` on each row (apply is similar to a for-loop, but neater to write and read).

```
apply(dataset, 1, numberAfterFirstOne)
[1]  0  1  0  0  1 NA
```

This is similar to the more clumpsy construction with a for-loop:

```
result <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(dataset)){
  result[i] <- numberAfterFirstOne(dataset[i, ])
}
```

You could now tweak the function to return what you want. At the moment there could be 0, 1, or NA returned, maybe you just want 1 and 0 or 1 and NA. The check with `if (length(x+1))` would not be necessary, because if the index is out of bounce, NA is returned by `myRow[x+1]` which would make the function even simpler.

You could also modify the code, so that the year is also returned:

```
colnames(dataset) <- 2007:2020 # name the columns of the example dataset

numberAfterFirstOne <- function(myRow){
  x <- which(myRow == 1)[1]
  return(c(x, myRow[x + 1])) # return the column index + the value
}

result <- apply(dataset, 1, numberAfterFirstOne) #save the result
result[1, ] <- names(dataset)[result[1, ]] # set column index to name of dataset column
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]
[1,] "2007" "2007" "2012" "2007" "2008" NA  
[2,] "0"    "1"    "0"    "0"    "1"    NA
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have a question regarding your example data set. I thought that m = 16 leads to the coloums V1 to V16 and that n= 5 would lead to the rows. But I do not undertand why n = 5 but there are 6 rows in the table. Can you please explain/clearify that to me?

Comment: There are 5 rows and then I've added another one with only zeros ``rbind`` = "row bind" and ``rep(0, 16)`` = repeat zero 16 times. I've did that to check if there are problems when no one is found at all and indeed the result is NA then where in the other cases it is 0 or 1. That could be improved by you now, if you wish or you keep it as additional information about the row.

Comment: If my answer helped you, feel free to upvote or accept it. That is how stackexchange-sites work.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. I accepted it know, I just needed some time to also get it working with my own data.